# PHP: Echo array de una consulta a base de datos Oracle

Tags: php, sql, array, echo

Hola tengo el resultado de una consulta sql en un array, base de datos oracle, pero no puedo imprimirlo, este es el array:

```
array(3) { ["rows_count"]=> int(6) ["result"]=> array(6) { [0]=> array(7) { ["ID"]=> string(2) "42" ["RUTUSUARIO"]=> string(8) "13235195" ["FECHAINICIO"]=> string(24) "21/10/21 00:00:00.000000" ["FECHAFIN"]=> string(24) "04/11/21 23:59:59.000000" ["EJECUCIONINICIO"]=> NULL ["EJECUCIONFIN"]=> NULL ["GESTOR_TERMINO"]=> NULL } [1]=> array(7) { ["ID"]=> string(2) "47" ["RUTUSUARIO"]=> string(8) "11888398" ["FECHAINICIO"]=> string(24) "21/10/21 00:00:00.000000" ["FECHAFIN"]=> string(24) "04/11/21 23:59:59.000000" ["EJECUCIONINICIO"]=> NULL ["EJECUCIONFIN"]=> NULL ["GESTOR_TERMINO"]=> NULL } [2]=> array(7) { ["ID"]=> string(2) "21" ["RUTUSUARIO"]=> string(8) "17051056" ["FECHAINICIO"]=> string(24) "15/01/21 00:00:00.000000" ["FECHAFIN"]=> string(24) "26/01/21 00:00:00.000000" ["EJECUCIONINICIO"]=> string(24) "25/01/21 12:11:14.463486" ["EJECUCIONFIN"]=> string(24) "29/01/21 04:00:02.378717" ["GESTOR_TERMINO"]=> NULL } [3]=> array(7) { ["ID"]=> string(2) "57" ["RUTUSUARIO"]=> string(8) "79817130" ["FECHAINICIO"]=> string(24) "22/10/21 00:00:00.000000" ["FECHAFIN"]=> string(24) "05/11/21 23:59:59.000000" ["EJECUCIONINICIO"]=> NULL ["EJECUCIONFIN"]=> NULL ["GESTOR_TERMINO"]=> NULL } [4]=> array(7) { ["ID"]=> string(2) "58" ["RUTUSUARIO"]=> string(8) "61509000" ["FECHAINICIO"]=> string(24) "26/10/21 00:00:00.000000" ["FECHAFIN"]=> string(24) "09/11/21 23:59:59.000000" ["EJECUCIONINICIO"]=> NULL ["EJECUCIONFIN"]=> string(24) "25/10/21 17:03:06.819286" ["GESTOR_TERMINO"]=> NULL } [5]=> array(7) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "6" ["RUTUSUARIO"]=> string(8) "21229820" ["FECHAINICIO"]=> string(24) "10/10/20 00:00:00.000000" ["FECHAFIN"]=> string(24) "13/10/21 23:59:59.000000" ["EJECUCIONINICIO"]=> string(24) "13/10/20 09:17:06.289173" ["EJECUCIONFIN"]=> string(24) "29/10/21 14:56:47.870905" ["GESTOR_TERMINO"]=> string(3) "123" } } ["inserted_id"]=> NULL }
```

intente imprimirlo de estas dos formas pero ninguna funciona

```
    $sql_conexion = new sql_functions();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_anulamedico";
    $result = $sql_conexion->executeQuery($sql);
    var_dump($result);
    //echo ($result['rows_count']);

    foreach($result['rows_count'] as $value){
        foreach($value['result'] as $data_value){
            echo ($data_value['ID']);

        }
    }
    echo $result['rows_count']['result']['ID'];
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: No debe ser foreach($result as $value) ?  $result['rows_count'] solo sería la última entrada del array.

Comment: Intenta con `foreach( $result['result'] as $row ) var_dump($row);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los datos que estarías buscando se encuentran dentro de un conjunto de arrays anidados en la clave `result` de tu variable `$result`:

```
  ["result"]=> array(6) { 
    [0]=> array(7) { ["ID"]=> string(2) "42" ["RUTUSUARIO"]=> string(8) "13235195" ["FECHAINICIO"]=> string(24) "21/10/21 00:00:00.000000" ["FECHAFIN"]=> string(24) "04/11/21 23:59:59.000000" ["EJECUCIONINICIO"]=> NULL ["EJECUCIONFIN"]=> NULL ["GESTOR_TERMINO"]=> NULL } 
    [1]=> array(7) { ["ID"]=> string(2) "47" ["RUTUSUARIO"]=> string(8) "11888398" ["FECHAINICIO"]=> string(24) "21/10/21 00:00:00.000000" ["FECHAFIN"]=> string(24) "04/11/21 23:59:59.000000" ["EJECUCIONINICIO"]=> NULL ["EJECUCIONFIN"]=> NULL ["GESTOR_TERMINO"]=> NULL } 

... etc ...
```

Por tanto, la forma de leerlo sería así:

```
foreach($result['result'] as $row) {
    echo $row['ID'].' '.$row['RUTUSUARIO'].PHP_EOL; #... etc ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu array no está siendo recorrido, por la estructura que veo en tu arreglo tu `$result` está de esta forma (si lo hicieramos de manera manual)

```
    $result = array(
      "rows_count" => 6, "result" => Array(..."todo tus datos de consulta")
    );
```

Lo que intentas hacer es acceder a la posicion `result` desde `rows_count` pero no rows_count no tiene a result, result es una posición aparte, `rows_count`únicamente te informa la cantidad de filas que trajo tu consulta en la bd

```
foreach($result['result'] as $value){
    echo $value['ID'];        
}
```

De esta manera accedemos a `result` el cual contiene todos los datos de tu consulta.
Te recomiendo debuggear para este tipo de problemas, ayuda bastante Saludos.